# WordPress table (using TablePress) set column font to italics

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created a table in a blog created in `WordPress`. I have used `TablePress` plugin to create the table. Now I would want to set the left column font to italics (except the table header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the page and some web search, I came up with the following `CSS`:

```
.tablepress-id-1 tbody .column-1 {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Let me explain. You see, in `.tablepress-id-1`, the digit after the last `-` is the `shortcode` of the table created with `TablePress`. Secondly, I would like to apply the CSS for the table body only, hence `tbody`. And finally, `.column-1` implies the leftmost column of the table.

To set the CSS, you need to go to `TablePress -> Plugin Options` from the WordPress Admin page (I assume you have the TablePress plugin is installed), then write your CSS in `Custom CSS` text area and click `Save Changes`.

Comment: If you already know the answer, then why do you ask the question?

Comment: Stackoverflow actually encourages it - https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/. To quote `To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.`. Secondly, I did not get the answer instantly after some Google search,so I saved the trouble for anyone in future who is pretty much newbie like me and looking for the solution.

Comment: I do not deny with the above article, it is just that there are already so many resources available for similar question and if you had just searched the search engine, you would have easily got the answer for your question.

Comment: Perhaps, you're right. As I said, there will be folks with different level of expertise. For me, I know what CSS is and how to inspect a page source, but it was not known to me how to use a custom CSS is the first place in TablePress, let alone what will the CSS look like to get my desired effect. Again, to someone expert it is trivial, but my whole intention is and will be to share the knowledge for a person easily and comprehensively. Frankly, my intention is not to raise reputation. I was stuck with this problem for some time and when I got the solution, I posted both at once. Thank you.